# Reading a BLOB from Oracle Database using cx_Oracle.lob.read() is not working

Tags: python, scipy, cx-oracle

I tried to read the BLOB data from an Oracle database in python but when I print it and try to save it in .mat file, the data is all gibberish.

It seems like the BLOB itself is getting corrupted when reading from the database in python.

```
import cx_Oracle
import scipy.io


filename = "test.mat"
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', '1521', service_name='xxxxxxxx') 
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='xxxx', password='xxxx', dsn=dsn_tns) 

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(
        """
      select * from 
(
    select 

        i.mat_file
    from 
        schema.BAW__MATFILES l,
        schema.BAW__MATFILES s,
       schema.BAW__MATFILES w,
       schema.BAW__MATFILES i
    where 
        s.parent_id=l.node_id
        and w.parent_id=s.node_id
        and i.parent_id=w.node_id

        and l.field_name='1912110'
        and l.is_deleted='N' and l.is_root='Y'

        and s.field_name='AFTER_PA_TRIM'
        and s.is_deleted='N' and s.is_root='Y'

        and w.is_root='Y'
        and w.field_name='1'
        and w.is_deleted='N' and w.is_root='Y'

        and i.field_name='FilterMap'
        and i.is_deleted='N' and i.is_root='N'

    order by i.time_stamp desc
)
where rownum<2
"""
) 
rows =  c.fetchone()


print (rows[0].read())

blobdata = rows[0].read()
print(type(blobdata))
#print (blobdata)

#print(scipy.io.whosmat('datafile.mat'))

conn.close()

scipy.io.savemat('datafile.mat', {'blobData': blobdata})
```

I finally got it working by converting the BLOB data to numpy using the code below:

```
blobdata = np.array(rows[7].read())
print(type(blobdata))
print (blobdata)

#print(scipy.io.whosmat('datafile.mat'))


c.close()
conn.close()
f = open('test.mat', 'w+b')
binary_format = bytearray(blobdata)
f.write(binary_format)
f.close()
```

Comment: Check it really is a BLOB, not a CLOB - you may want to use `encoding` parameter in your `connect()` call to avoid characterset conversion.  Check the data was inserted correctly - use another tool to query it.  Try writing the data with a standard filesystem function in Python, see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files. Finally, for BLOBs less than 1GB that can be held in memory, you will get better performance with an outtypehandler, see https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ReturnLobsAsStrings.py

Comment: Thanks Christopher , I tried writing the file with standard file system already without any change in the output :(.
Regarding the data , there is already a C# application that access these blobs , so they are written correctly into database for sure, but I need to double check the encoding . Thanks for your input.

Comment: I got it to working by converting the blobdata to np.array like
   
blobdata = np.array(rows[7].read())
print(type(blobdata))
print (blobdata)

#print(scipy.io.whosmat('datafile.mat'))


c.close()
conn.close()
f = open('test.mat', 'w+b')
binary_format = bytearray(blobdata)
f.write(binary_format)
f.close()

Answer (score 0):

Finally , I got this working , I converted the blobdata to numpy array using below code and now i see the MAT file created correctly.

```
blobdata = np.array(rows[7].read())
print(type(blobdata))
print (blobdata)

#print(scipy.io.whosmat('datafile.mat'))


c.close()
conn.close()
f = open('test.mat', 'w+b')
binary_format = bytearray(blobdata)
f.write(binary_format)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of cx_Oracle](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html) offers a solution.

**CLOBs and BLOBs smaller than 1 GB can queried from the database directly as strings and bytes**. A Connection.outputtypehandler or Cursor.outputtypehandler needs to be used as shown in this example:

```
def OutputTypeHandler(cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale):
    if defaultType == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_CLOB:
        return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_LONG, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
    if defaultType == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_BLOB:
        return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_LONG_RAW, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)

idVal = 1
textData = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
bytesData = b"Some binary data"
cursor.execute("insert into lob_tbl (id, c, b) values (:1, :2, :3)",
        [idVal, textData, bytesData])

connection.outputtypehandler = OutputTypeHandler
cursor.execute("select c, b from lob_tbl where id = :1", [idVal])
clobData, blobData = cursor.fetchone()
print("CLOB length:", len(clobData))
print("CLOB data:", clobData)
print("BLOB length:", len(blobData))
print("BLOB data:", blobData)
```

The code above prints:

```
CLOB length: 43
CLOB data: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
BLOB length: 16
BLOB data: b'Some binary data'
```